# Is there a central DB SERVER in this kind of situation?

Tags: distributed, environment

I have multiple servers containing the same table schema, but each responsible for a portion of the overall data. No one machine needs to contain all the data. Each machine only contains data relating to its department.

Is there a central database server which will contain all the data, or just a central database server which can be used to access the other servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are doing is partitioning the data. Remember the [CAP Theorem](http://www.julianbrowne.com/article/viewer/brewers-cap-theorem) states you cannot have accessibility and data consistency all the time in this configuration. Normally you'd have data servers (like in your example) and then different servers for read/writing using something like SQL. They can be distributed (just as long as they know about all the data servers). Just remember that 'in a distributed system there is no central arbiter of truth'.

We use the same came of setup in a production network, where the faster servers are a cluster with the last 2 years worth of data and then there are slower archive servers. Results can span the entire collection of servers depending on the query. If a report needs archived data it queries a separate server that performs a join behind the scenes.